# ValidationSummary not Rendering for IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11, validationsummary

I have a ValidationSummary control that is working fine with firefox and previous versions of internet explorer except for IE11. I have this aspx markup:

```
<asp:validationsummary id="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" CssClass="VALIDATIONSUMMARY" DisplayMode="List"></asp:validationsummary>
```

In firefox, and all other browsers I've tried outside of IE11, this generates:

```
<div id="ctl00_cphBody_ValidationSummary1" class="VALIDATIONSUMMARY" style="color:Red;display:none;"></div>
```

However, in IE11 this div tag does not appear in the generated output. Any ideas?

Comment: provide as much code as you can please so we can test your scenario.

Comment: Please post the ASPX file, CS file and the CSS file that contains VALIDATIONSUMMARY